# AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'utils'

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, anaconda3

OS: MacOS Monterey (12.4)
Chip: Apple Silicon M1
Env: Conda 4.12.0
Python: 3.9.12
TensorFlow version: 2.9.0, installed through `pip install tensorflow-macos`

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/okihita/PycharmProjects/TFFlowerClassification/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    training_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'utils'
```

Here's my `main.py` code:

```
import pathlib

import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image

data_dir = pathlib.Path('aksara-batak/toba')

aksara = list(data_dir.glob('a/*'))

img_height = 30
img_width = 30

training_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width)
)
```

Did I import the wrong version of TensorFlow?